# Why anonymous oracle stored procedure is working but named not

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a simple SP in the Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 which will execute a simple update statement like

```
update t set col1 = 1 where col2 = 2;
```

When i'm doing it in the anonymous stored procedure it works fine

```
begin
     update t set col1 = 1 where col2 = 2;
end;
```

But if I'm trying to create a procedure

```
create or replace procedure p as 
begin
     update t set col1 = 1 where col2 = 2;
end;
```

And trying to run it, i'm gets a lot of errors:

```
ORA-06550: line 9, column 13:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_SQL' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 9, column 13:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 16, column 13:
PLS-00201: identifier 'SYS.DBMS_LOB' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 16, column 13:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
```

Can any one explain how it happened, why sp is trying to get objects from SYS schema? Why it works in case of anonymous sp and not working in case of named SP?

Comment: What code do you use to run your procedure?

Comment: I run it from SQL Developer

Comment: suppose he says how could you call your s.p. from the command line literally.

Comment: By the way, Are packages(dbms_sql and dbms_lob) granted to public?

Comment: do you run `exec p;` or `begin p; end;` ?

Comment: Different security paradigm. When executing a named procedure, execute rights to SYS packs much be granted explicitly to the schema owner.